# Loading car photo's

Tags: javascript, array, image, url

I have been developing a small application for a client which combines two arrays together and then creates a URL and then loads the images on the same page from the given URL.

I'd like you to look at my code and give feedback on how to make it more maintainable and robust.

```
function displayContent() {
    document.getElementById("findCar").onsubmit = function () {
        var registration = document.getElementById("regPlate").value,
            reference = document.getElementById("stockRef").value;
        var regArray = registration.split(''),
            refArray = reference.split(''),
            referenceNinth = refArray[10];
        reverseReg = regArray.reverse();
        var obfuscated = new Array();
        var obf_index = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            obfuscated[obf_index] = refArray[i];
            obf_index++;
            obfuscated[obf_index] = reverseReg[i];
            obf_index++;
        }
        obfuscated.push(referenceNinth);
        obfuscatedString = obfuscated.join("");
        var camera = new Array();
        var cameraSize = "350";
        var cam_index = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
            if (i > 0) cameraSize = "800";
            camera[cam_index++] = cameraSize + "/f";
            camera[cam_index++] = cameraSize + "/i";
            camera[cam_index++] = cameraSize + "/6";
            camera[cam_index++] = cameraSize + "/5";
            camera[cam_index++] = cameraSize + "/4";
            camera[cam_index++] = cameraSize + "/r";
        }
        for (i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'http://imagecache.arnoldclark.com/imageserver/" + obfuscatedString + "/" + camera[i] + "'
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
    return false;
    };

}
```

Comment: Could you explain better what your code does? Your first paragraph doesn't make any sense at all. "Combining two arrays" could mean anything. And what do two arrays (of what?) have to do with the creation of an URL? And what's "the same page"? The "page" of the URL? The page in which your script is running?

Answer (score 1):

From a once over:

- obfuscating urls from the javascript side will not stop any dedicated individual
- `displayContent` is an unfortunate name for the function, it does not give away that all it does it setting a listener, consider `setFindCarListener`
- `var obfuscated = []` is considered better than `var obfuscated = new Array();`
- It is considered better form to have a single `var` statement
- `reverseReg` is an unfortunate name, it is unclear to me what it is supposed to contain
- Don't assign `onsubmit`, use `addEventListener` instead
- A loop that will only run twice should get unrolled ( `for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {` ), I would put the code in the loop block inside a helper function
- You have some indentation trouble, consider using jsbeautifier
- `obf_index++` increases `obf_index` after evaluating it, so you can do

  ```
  for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
      obfuscated[obf_index++] = refArray[i];
      obfuscated[obf_index++] = reverseReg[i];
  }
  ```
- Since you start from `0`, you are really simulating `push`, so you could also do

  ```
  for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
      obfuscated.push( refArray[i] );
      obfuscated.push( reverseReg[i] );
  }
  ```
- lowerCamelCase is preferred in JavaScript so `obf_index` -> `obfIndex` -> `obfuscatedIndex`
- You use both single quotes and double quotes for strings, stick to single quotes
- Use JsHint.com, you are not declaring every variable with `var`
- `refArray` is like reverse polish notation, postfixing the type of the variable, `regChars` would be a better name, it tells me that this contains the characters of the reg(istration)

All in all ( this is untested ), I would go with something like this:

```
function addCameraEntries( array , cameraSize ) {
    array.push( cameraSize + "/f" );
    array.push( cameraSize + "/i" );
    array.push( cameraSize + "/6" );
    array.push( cameraSize + "/5" );
    array.push( cameraSize + "/4" );
    array.push( cameraSize + "/r" );
}

function setFindCarListener() {

    document.getElementById("findCar").addEvenListener( "submit", function onSubmit() {
        var registration = document.getElementById("regPlate").value,
            reference = document.getElementById("stockRef").value,
            referenceChars = reference.split(''),
            ninthReference = referenceChars[10];
            registrationChars = registration.split('').reverse(),
            obfuscated = [],
            camera = [];
        for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            obfuscated.push( referenceChars[i] );
            obfuscated.push( registrationChars[i] );
        }
        obfuscated.push(ninthReference);
        obfuscatedString = obfuscated.join("");
        addCameraEntries( camera , '350' );
        addCameraEntries( camera , '800' );
        for (i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = 'http://imagecache.arnoldclark.com/imageserver/" + obfuscatedString + "/" + camera[i] + "'
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        }
        return false;
    };

}
```